# Correct way to implement bitcoin:<address> URI handling in Gnome desktop

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

I run bitcoin-qt all the time, so I set the browser to handle bitcoin: URI with bitcoin-qt.
Unfortunately that causes a new instance to be started, which fails coz it fails to get a lock on the database.

What's the best way to do this?

I have 'server=1' to enable json-rpc access to bitcoin-qt.

Do I need to set the browser to handle these links with (say) bitcoin-cli?
Or do I need to reconfigure the whole thing and run bitcoind as well?

Comment: I've duplicated the question on askubuntu as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383898/bitcoin-uri-handling

Comment: My question isn't about general URI handling tho. It's only bitcoin that I have the problem with.

Even a mp4 link works when (say) vlc is already running. There's no issue with locking of course, but vlc has an option to run a new instance or start the video in the existing instance.

That's why I'm here. It's very bitcoin specific, but I feel sure there's a 'best' way to handle it.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to reproduce this. For me it does not try to run another `bitcoin-qt` instead its added as second address in send form: https://i.imgur.com/Isfcm89.png

Comment: Ouch! That's what I want.
What is that '-W1' in the title? Is that relevant?
Mine is v22.0.0

Comment: Just to confirm: you had bitcoin-qt already running when you clicked that link?

Comment: W1 is name of wallet. Even I tried it using Bitcoin Core 22.0 and Browser chromium in Ubuntu. Yes bitcoin-qt was already running when I clicked the `bitcoin:address` URI link.

Comment: Maybe my desktop file is bad. Does this look like yours?

[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Name=Bitcoin

Icon=/home/xxx/.local/share/icons/bitcoin.svg

Exec=/usr/bin/bitcoin-qt -min -testnet=0 -regtest=0

Terminal=false

Hidden=false

Comment: Thanks for your time btw. This is looking like a bad configuration on my end somehow.

Comment: OK. I got it working! It needed a parameter (%U) in the exec line of the desktop file.

Comment: For anyone else trying this, note that the BIP-21 bitcoin wiki page (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0021) examples of bitcoin:<address> links don't work. They are invalid addresses now for some reason. I needed to get a link from bitrefill to get this thing to behave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that when the parameter '%U' is missing from the 'Exec' line in a gnome/Ubuntu desktop file, the OS creates a new instance whenever the application is called (in this case by the browser on clicking a bitcoin: link on a web page). That fails when the application can only have one instance running (bitcoin-qt by itself handles the bitcoin database; no other app/instance can be simultaneously doing this).

The 'magic' is that when the '%U' parameter is present, the OS sends the request to the running app and, in this case, that appears as a bitcoin transaction in bitcoin-qt as expected.

Over the years of playing with bitcoin.desktop, i had managed to lose that parameter somehow. Very confusing.